# Syntax for a SQL query

Tags: sql, syntax

```
k=conn:query({live=true,sql ="select DISTINCT O.OrderId, (SELECT R.ReportBody + (char(13)+char(10)) + 'Modified By: ' + UM.FirstName + ' at ' + UM.LastName + (char(13)+char(10)) +'Authored By: ' + UC.FirstName + ' at ' + UC.LastName + (char(13)+char(10)) + (char(13)+char(10)) AS [text()] FROM dbo.OrderReports R INNER JOIN dbo.Users UM ON R.ModifiedById = UM.UserId INNER JOIN dbo.Users UC ON R.CreatedById = UC.UserId WHERE R.OrderId = M[1].OrderId ORDER BY R.CreateDate DESC FOR XML PATH('')) 'OrderReport'FROM dbo.Orders O "})
```

I have above mentioned query and I am getting incorrect syntax error at `where R.OrderId = M[1].OrderId` , I am using sql with Lua.
P.S: The value in M[1].OrderId is a uniqueidentifier.

But if I have this query:

```
  mk = conn:query({live = true, sql= "select ReportBody,DENSE_RANK() over (Order by ModifyDate DESC) from OrderReports where OrderId = '"..M[1].OrderId.."'"})
```

It works with M[1].OrderId though M[1].OrderId gives syntax error in the first query. How can I fix this in first query?

Comment: do the same for your first query, .i.e. `..... where OrderId = '"..M[1].OrderId.."'  ORDER BY .... etc"`

Comment: @cha: No, obviously I can't put double quotes right there in the middle of sql query, it will expect it to end there

Comment: try it. obviously, you can. It is called "string literals concatenation". Supported by most programming languages, including your language of choice, as demonstrated by your second example

Comment: @cha: I tried, did not work and it's allowed to be used in languages but sql has its own syntax and I can't use some other language's syntax in the middle of a sql query, it has to give an error then

Comment: is your query working when you use it in the Query Analyser?

Comment: Actually, I am using Iguana software and having sql query as part of my LUa program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you have not answered my last question. But assuming that the query you have written is working this is what you are after:

```
k=conn:query({live=true,sql ="select DISTINCT O.OrderId, (SELECT R.ReportBody + (char(13)+char(10)) + 'Modified By: ' + UM.FirstName + ' at ' + UM.LastName + (char(13)+char(10)) +'Authored By: ' + UC.FirstName + ' at ' + UC.LastName + (char(13)+char(10)) + (char(13)+char(10)) AS [text()] FROM dbo.OrderReports R INNER JOIN dbo.Users UM ON R.ModifiedById = UM.UserId INNER JOIN dbo.Users UC ON R.CreatedById = UC.UserId WHERE R.OrderId = '"..M[1].OrderId.."' ORDER BY R.CreateDate DESC FOR XML PATH('')) 'OrderReport'FROM dbo.Orders O "})
```